# Parse JSON with "cyrillic"

Tags: json, parsing, swift4

I have a JSON with "cyrillic", and I don't know how to parse it correctly :

```
roles =         {
            "\U0430\U043d\U0430\U043b\U0438\U0442\U0438\U043a\U0430.\U043c\U043e\U0431" =             (
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                5,
                9
            );
"\U0440\U0435\U043f\U0435\U0440\U0442\U0443\U0430\U0440" = "+";
    };
```

How I can parse it to entity?

Comment: The problem is _not_ the Cyrillic. It's the dot in the key name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If variable in JSON name contains ".", you need to use codingKeys to encode your json:

```
struct Data: Codable{
    let roles: Roles
}
    struct Roles: Codable {
        var cinemasIds: [String]

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case cinemasIds = "а.м"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.  Please explain.